# ruby to_xml set root attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, data-conversion

I need to convert a ruby hash to xml. Here is the hash:

```
hash = {
      "AffiliateInfo" => {
      "Username" => '123456',
      "Password" => "Mypass",
      "TrackingCampaign" => "MyTrackingCampaign",
      "Env" => "production"
    }
  }
```

and the xml I wanted to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InsuranceRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AffiliateInfo>
  <Username>12696</Username>
  <Password>MyPassword</Password>
  <TrackingCampaign>MyTrackingCampaign</TrackingCampaign>
  <LeadSourceID>SourceID</LeadSourceID>
  <ProductionEnvironment>true</ProductionEnvironment>
  </AffiliateInfo>
</InsuranceRequest>
```

When I do:

```
hash.to_xml(root: 'InsuranceRequest')
```

I get the following xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InsuranceRequest>
  <AffiliateInfo>
    <Username>123456</Username>
    <Password>Mypass</Password>
    <TrackingCampaign>MyTrackingCampaign</TrackingCampaign>
    <Env>production</Env>
  </AffiliateInfo>
</InsuranceRequest>
```

The output is missing the properties of the root node attributes:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

I cannot add attributes to the root node. Is there a way to add these attributes using `to_xml` method?

Please suggest if there is any other means to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use custom builder. Here is example with Nokogiri builder

```
require 'nokogiri'

hash = {"AffiliateInfo" => {
          "Username" => '123456',
          "Password" => "Mypass",
          "TrackingCampaign" => "MyTrackingCampaign",
          "Env" => "production"
         }
       }


builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.InsuranceRequest('xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xmlns:xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema') do
    xml.AffiliateInfo do
      hash['AffiliateInfo'].each do |k, v|
        xml.send(k, v)
      end
    end
  end
end

builder.to_xml
```

This produces the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InsuranceRequest
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AffiliateInfo>
        <Username>123456</Username>
        <Password>Mypass</Password>
        <TrackingCampaign>MyTrackingCampaign</TrackingCampaign>
        <Env>production</Env>
    </AffiliateInfo>
</InsuranceRequest>
```

Please note that `hash` should be defined **before** builder

Here is Nokogiri documentation http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder